# How to display modal instead of options in select input with selection?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I'm using React and django to test some projects and I'm a newbie.
I want to display a Modal box instead of dropdown options (options are my API data) of a selection in form and let the user select those options (fruits) in a modal box and add multiple selected fruits to Fruitbox (Box element)

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-blackwell-nh6n5?fontsize=14) is what I tried.

Does anyone know how this code will look like?

Comment: Your demo doesn't show a functioning example of what you are trying to look for. Did you give the proper link?

Comment: Why? i'm looking for a Modal box instead of options list of a select input element and let users put that items in Box element.